Computation method for the minimal polynomial of an operator $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$. ("Linear Algebra Done Right Fourth Edition" by Sheldon Axler.)
I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right Fourth Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

5.22 Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$. Then there is a unique monic polynomial $p\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$ of smallest degree such that $p(T)=0$. Furthermore, $\deg p\leq\dim V$.


Even faster (usually), pick $v\in V$ and consider the equation $$c_0v+c_1Tv+\cdots+c_{\dim V-1}T^{\dim V-1}v=-T^{\dim V}v.$$
Use a basis of $V$ to convert the equation above to a system of $\dim V$ linear equations in $\dim V$ unknowns $c_0,c_1,\dots,c_{\dim V-1}$. If this system of equations has a unique solution $c_0,c_1,\dots,c_{\dim V-1}$ (as happens most of the time), then the scalars $c_0,c_1,\dots,c_{\dim V-1},1$ are the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of $T$ (because 5.22 states that the degree of the minimal polynomial is at most $\dim V$).

If the system of equations has a unique solution $c_0,c_1,\dots,c_{\dim V-1}$, then the scalars $c_0,c_1,\dots,c_{\dim V-1},1$ are the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of $T$ because 5.22 states that the degree of the minimal polynomial is at most $\dim V$.
Why?
My proof of this fact is as follows:

Suppose that $c_0v+c_1Tv+\cdots+c_{\dim V-1}T^{\dim V-1}v=-T^{\dim V}v$ has a unique solution.
Let $c_0,c_1,\dots,c_{\dim V-1}$ be the unique solution for $c_0v+c_1Tv+\cdots+c_{\dim V-1}T^{\dim V-1}v=-T^{\dim V}v$.
Assume that there exists the minimal polynomial of $T$ whose degree $k$ is less than $\dim V$.
Let $d_0+d_1z+\cdots+d_{k-1}z^{k-1}+z^k$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$.
Then, $d_0I+d_1T+\cdots+d_{k-1}T^{k-1}+T^k=0$.
So, $d_0v+d_1Tv+\cdots+d_{k-1}T^{k-1}v+T^kv=0$.
So, $(c_0+d_0)v+(c_1+d_1)Tv+\cdots+(c_k+1)T^kv+\cdots+c_{\dim V-1}T^{\dim V-1}v+T^{\dim V}v=0$.
Since $c_k\neq c_k+1$, the solution for $c_0v+c_1Tv+\cdots+c_{\dim V-1}T^{\dim V-1}v=-T^{\dim V}v$ is not unique.
This is a contradiction.


It is not clear what you are asking. Are you asking why the degree of the minimal polynomial is $\le \dim V$?

@copper.hat thank you very much for your comment. I wondered where the author used the fact the degree of the minimal polynomial is at most $\dim V$. But thanks to your comment, now I understand where the author used the fact.

You seem to be asking where this sentence uses the fact that the minimal polynomial has degree at most $\dim(V)$. That is because the condition that the mentioned equation mentioned (for fixed $v$ and with the coefficients $c_i$ as unknowns) has any solution is equivalent to the existence of a monic polynomial $P$ of degree $\dim(V)$ such that $P[T](v)=0$; the fact that the minimal polynomial $\mu_T$ has degree at most $\dim(V)$ ensures that one can take $P$ to be any monic multiple of $\mu_T$ to get a solution (one that works independently of $v$). And if there is a unique solution (for given $v$), then $\mu_T$ can have only one such monic multiple, which requires it to be of degree$~\dim(V)$ and the multiple will be $\mu_T$ itself; the uniqueness of the solution then implies that it gives you $\mu_T$.

I wondered where the author used the fact the degree of the minimal polynomial is at most $\dim V$.
But thanks to copper.hat's comment, now I understand where the author used the fact.

Suppose that $c_0v+c_1Tv+\cdots+c_{\dim V-1}T^{\dim V-1}v=-T^{\dim V}v$ has a unique solution.
Let $c_0,c_1,\dots,c_{\dim V-1}$ be the unique solution for $c_0v+c_1Tv+\cdots+c_{\dim V-1}T^{\dim V-1}v=-T^{\dim V}v$.
Assume that there exists the minimal polynomial of $T$ whose degree $k$ is less than $\dim V$.
Let $d_0+d_1z+\cdots+d_{k-1}z^{k-1}+z^k$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$.
Then, $d_0I+d_1T+\cdots+d_{k-1}T^{k-1}+T^k=0$.
So, $d_0v+d_1Tv+\cdots+d_{k-1}T^{k-1}v+T^kv=0$.
So, $(c_0+d_0)v+(c_1+d_1)Tv+\cdots+(c_k+1)T^kv+\cdots+c_{\dim V-1}T^{\dim V-1}v+T^{\dim V}v=0$.
Since $c_k\neq c_k+1$, the solution for $c_0v+c_1Tv+\cdots+c_{\dim V-1}T^{\dim V-1}v=-T^{\dim V}v$ is not unique.
This is a contradiction.
So, the degree of the minimal polynomial of $T$ is greater than or equal to $\dim V$.
But by 5.22, there is a unique monic polynomial $p\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$ of smallest degree such that $p(T)=0$ and $\deg p\leq\dim V$.
So, the degree of the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $\dim V$.
Let $p(z)=b_0+b_1z+\cdots+b_{\dim V-1}z^{\dim V-1}+z^{\dim V}$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$.
Then, $b_0+b_1T+\cdots+b_{\dim V-1}T^{\dim V-1}+T^{\dim V}=0$.
So, $b_0v+b_1Tv+\cdots+b_{\dim V-1}T^{\dim V-1}v+T^{\dim V}v=0$.
So, $b_0v+b_1Tv+\cdots+b_{\dim V-1}T^{\dim V-1}v=-T^{\dim V}v$.
By the uniqueness of the solution for $c_0v+c_1Tv+\cdots+c_{\dim V-1}T^{\dim V-1}v=-T^{\dim V}v$, $b_i=c_i$ for $i=0,\dots,\dim V-1$.
Therefore, $$c_0+c_1z+\cdots+c_{\dim V-1}z^{\dim V-1}+z^{\dim V}=b_0+b_1z+\cdots+b_{\dim V-1}z^{\dim V-1}+z^{\dim V}$$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$.

